# What is this strange expansion slot on the back of an old HP Pavilion Desktop?

Tags: desktop

I was popping the rear expansion slot covers out of the back of this old PC (HP Pavilion XE783) and noticed that there was an odd expansion slot in the rear that is quite different than a normal slot and is far away from the rest (top right of picture, above where the power supply is) and decided to pop it out.

[image: Rear of PC]

It doesn't have any components on the inside, and the back of the DVD drive is a few inches away. It appears to have 2 screw holes nearby, one on each side. Does anyone have any idea of what this is for?

Comment: Based on [these specs](https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-pavilion-xe783-tower-celeron-700-mhz-64-mb-30-gb-p1372a/) that *might* be the area where the “Fax / modem - PCI - plug-in card” would be installed. But honestly no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is one of these external SCSI Connectors. Specifically, the low density ones. They would’ve been fairly common during this computer’s lifetime.

[image]